# Fix vim coc including headers in C files

Tags: c, linux, vim, header, coc.nvim

I am using vim with coc vim for the autocompletion.
Coc is just great with python, java etc, and it is really easy to install and use.

However while coding in C, i noticed that sometimes coc-clangd adds a header on its own at the beginning (for example #include <cstddef.h> ). Because of that i have problems compiling ...
I am 80% sure that the problem is from coc-clangd.

Did someone ever had that problem before ? Can you please tell me how to prevent coc from adding headers on its own ?

Thanks is advance

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker and/or official support channels.

Answer (score 1):

The header text is came from `clangd`, not `coc-clangd`. Some completion items from clangd came with a textEdit that includes a header text, coc.nvim applied the textEdit.

Comment: Do you know a way to prevent coc.nvim from applying the text edit ?